# Java 17 runtime kinesis lambda code doesnt work localstack (easy code)

Tags: amazon-web-services, eclipse, maven, amazon-kinesis, localstack

Its very simple. This code works as jar and lambda (maven project):

```
package test2;

import java.util.Map;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;

public class test implements RequestHandler<Map<String,String>, String>{

      @Override
      public String handleRequest(Map<String,String> event, Context context)
      {
        String prueba = "Prueba";
        return prueba;
      }
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Testing def");
      }
    }
```

Pom.xml with dependencies:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>test2</groupId>
  <artifactId>test2</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>17</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I export it as a runable jar, with its run configuration:
[export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXwkb.png); [runnable jar file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jz6O.png); [runable configuration and package required libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rT6h.png)

Later I go to localstack:

> aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 lambda create-function --function-name Test3 --runtime java17 --handler test2.test::handleRequest --role arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/RolLambda --zip-file fileb://./test.jar

> aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 lambda invoke --function-name Test3 output.json

Output: [It works!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFROp.png)

Now the code THAT DOESNT WORK as lambda (maven project too). I only added a kinesisclient object:

```
package main;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Map;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;

import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kinesis.KinesisClient;

public class Test implements RequestHandler<Map<String,String>, String>{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Testing def");
    }
    @Override
    public String handleRequest(Map<String,String> event, Context context)
    {
        String Error = "kinesis_Error";
        String prueba = "Prueba";
        
        try {
            KinesisClient kinesis_client = KinesisClient.builder().region(Region.US_EAST_1).endpointOverride(URI.create("http://127.0.0.1:4566")).build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Error;
        }
        
        return prueba;
    }
}
```

Pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>definitive_test</groupId>
  <artifactId>definitive_test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>17</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>kinesis</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.135</version>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I do the same steps:
-runnable jar with the [properly configuration set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjTtc.png)
-create lambda and make the execution:

> aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 lambda create-function --function-name Test3 --runtime java17 --handler main.Test::handleRequest --role arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/RolLambda --zip-file fileb://./test.jar

But now I get the unhandled:

> aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 lambda invoke --function-name Test3 output.json

```
{
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "FunctionError": "Unhandled",
    "ExecutedVersion": "$LATEST"
}
```

The output:

> {"errorMessage":"software/amazon/awssdk/services/kinesis/KinesisClient","errorType":"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError","stackTrace":["main.Test.handleRequest(Test.java:25)","java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)","java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)","java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)","java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)"],"cause":{"errorMessage":"software.amazon.awssdk.services.kinesis.KinesisClient","errorType":"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException","stackTrace":["java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)","java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)","java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)","main.Test.handleRequest(Test.java:25)","java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)","java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)","java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)","java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)"]}}

I don't know why this happens. I have already checked rol permissions. I think its ok (its the arn arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/RolLambda)

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "lambda:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket1/*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket1/*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
                "kinesis:PutRecord",
                "kinesis:PutRecords",
                "kinesis:GetRecords",
                "kinesis:GetShardIterator",
                "kinesis:DescribeStream",
                "kinesis:ListStreams"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the issue was the jar compilation. Here is the build of a **basic pom.xml** that put jar dependencies into final jar:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Productor</groupId>
    <artifactId>Productor</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Build an executable JAR with dependencies -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>productor.Productor</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Otras dependencias aquí -->
        <!-- Dependencia para el servicio de Amazon Kinesis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>kinesis</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.135</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dependencia para el servicio de Amazon S3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.135</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

You can put any **dependency** you need in **dependencies** flag. And you need to input your package and main class in **mainclass** flag (in my case productor.Productor). **Properties** set java version and encoding. Now with @smac2020 command **mvn package** you can make JAR file correctly.
Now I face a aws credential problem in a more complex code, but that's other history ':/

Comment: Notice that it's functional in **Maven projects**, other java projects weren't tested

Answer (score 3):

I will test that code. However - i will make a few changes.  1st to ensure all of the dependencies are included in your JAR, I will create a FAT JAR using:

**mvn package**

Then to test it, I will upload the JAR to the Lambda AWS console and directly invoke the Lambda function using the AWS Console.

By the way - your issues is this:

**errorMessage":"software/amazon/awssdk/services/kinesis/KinesisClient","errorType":"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError","stackTrace":**

The Kinesisclient cannot be found. This means you did not create the JAR properly.

**UPDATE**

As promised - here is the result. The code works when built with mvn package and deploying via AWS Lambda Console at
https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/lambda/home?region=us-east-1#/functions

The Java Code.

```
package org.example;

import java.util.Map;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kinesis.KinesisClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kinesis.model.ListShardsRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kinesis.model.ListShardsResponse;

public class TestHandler implements RequestHandler<Map<String,String>, String>{

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(Map<String,String> event, Context context)
    {
        String name = "LamDataStream";
        context.getLogger().log("*** Stream Name: " + name );
        KinesisClient kinesisClient = KinesisClient.builder()
            .region(Region.US_EAST_1)
            .build();

        ListShardsRequest request = ListShardsRequest.builder()
            .streamName(name)
            .build();

        ListShardsResponse response = kinesisClient.listShards(request);
        context.getLogger().log(name + " has " + response.shards());
        return name;
    }
}
```

I deployed it using the AWS Lambda console:

[image]

I tested it and it worked pefectly:

[image]

Here is output in logs:

[image]

Finally my POM (there may be a few extra dependencies):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestLambda</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.45</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>dynamodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-client</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk.crt</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-crt</artifactId>
            <version>0.25.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j2-impl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>textract</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>s3control</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>translate</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>comprehend</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20230227</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>polly</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-booter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>lambda</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>s3-transfer-manager</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>kinesis</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.45</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! After changing src to "main\Test.java" (not "org\example\TestHandler.java") and aplying your code and your pom.xml I get this error (aws lambda unhandled functionError code 200 ): {"errorMessage":"Error loading method handleRequest on class main.Test","errorType":"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError"}. The java code was modified to implement URI in kinesis object on line 19: `KinesisClient kinesis_client = KinesisClient.builder().region(Region.US_EAST_1).endpointOverride(URI.create("http://127.0.0.1:4566")).build();`

Comment: Your JAR is not being built successfully. How did you build it

Comment: I solved it! If you interested check the answer, many thanks.